# last-child selector with classname?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Can someone explain why last-child doesn't work when I use a classname selector with it? Is that not allowed?

http://jsfiddle.net/T2PgX/2/

Comment: You could use `:nth-of-type(N)` http://jsfiddle.net/xFb52/ Not really ideal though since this solution is tied to a specific html structure.

Comment: @alpaca lips: `:nth-of-type()` is effectively `:nth-child()` for `li` elements anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the `:last-child` of your list is not a `.group1`.

The selector `li.group1:last-child` doesn't mean "the last `li.group1` child"; it means "the `li` element that is the last child and has the 'group1' class".

Comment: So it's not possible? How can I get the last group1 element using CSS?

Comment: @Tony R: No, it's not possible with CSS selectors alone.